# Request the database through C# to return Persian values. query = like SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# code and I don't know why it doesn't work With this one, I search the database and return Persian and English values but it returns Persian values as null.

```cs
public List<Products> SearchByName(string query) 
{
    List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>() 
    {
        new SqlParameter("@query", $"%{query}%") 
    }; 
    return _exteranldata.GetFromCommand<Products>("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Products] WHERE name LIKE @query", param); 
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIYSX.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN7jG.jpg)

I try this code in the database to return Persian value but in c# code return is null

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Products] WHERE name LIKE '%می%'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp3o1.jpg)

I think the database type in sql server uses Persian_100_CI_AI
in connection string , i used "Charset=Persian_100_CI_AI;" once and "CodePage=1256" in the next try.

but return ex
1- exeption error System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'charset'.'
2- System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'codepage'.' column in table nvachar(50) and allow nu

function GetFromCommand

```cs
public List<ViewModel> GetFromCommand<ViewModel>(string nameSp, List<SqlParameter> parameters) where ViewModel : new()
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
                    cmd.CommandText = nameSp;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            List<ViewModel> list = new();
                            if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                Type entity = typeof(ViewModel);
                                Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> propDict = new();
                                PropertyInfo[] props = entity.GetProperties
                                (BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                                propDict = props.ToDictionary(p => p.Name.ToUpper(), p => p);
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    ViewModel newobject = new();

                                    for (int index = 0; index < reader.FieldCount; index++)
                                    {
                                        if (propDict.ContainsKey(reader.GetName(index).ToUpper()))
                                        {
                                            PropertyInfo info = propDict[reader.GetName(index).ToUpper()];
                                            if ((info != null) && info.CanWrite)
                                            {
                                                object val = reader.GetValue(index);
                                                info.SetValue(newobject, (val == DBNull.Value) ? null : val, null);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    list.Add(newobject);
                                }
                            }
                            return list;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        return new List<ViewModel>();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) cmd.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is `GetFromCommand` code ? With blind guess we can say that you are executing sqlcommand (changing and prolly reading using DbDataReader or some other library like Dapper) but you need to show at least how you doing this

Comment: @Selvin   hi, I updated the question
You can see the GetFromCommand code

Comment: First you should check if this query can be executed from microsoft management studio (so you would know that it is not a db settings problem)

Comment: also there is  Dapper ... (you are using very inefiecent code to reinvent the already existsings ORM) ... with Dapper,instead your Reflection code, you can simply use `connection.Query<ViewModel>` )

Comment: @Selvin  There is no problem with the database
I have done this review before (I don't know if the link of the images has been shown to you or not, but it shows the output of this work).

Comment: @Selvin I don't know how to use connection.Query<ViewModel> ....
How should I change it? ....
Please introduce me to a reference for learning if possible

Comment: In `WHERE name LIKE '%می%'` the parameter is *not* Unicode. Does `WHERE name LIKE '%می%'` work too? If not, it may be that the client and server codepages don't match *and* the server codepage is wrong. You should probably replace `GetFromCommand` with eg [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) and `connection.Query<ViewModel>(sql, new {query =$"%{query}%"});`. Just a single line, that's guaranteed to work, handle connections, parameters, names and mappings

Comment: You can't force the codepage with a connection setting. Your query is sending a perfectly valid and unambiguous Unicode string, containing Persian characters. Those are matched against the contents of the column. If the column isn't Unicode (ie nvarchar) and either uses the wrong encoding or the data saved there have the wrong encoding, the *correct* data sent from C# won't match

Answer (score 1):

Use [SQlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and add the [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Products] WHERE name LIKE @name")    
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", "%" + query + "%")
```

Comment: Thst's prolly `GetFromCommand` internally does (+ prolly it reads to `Products`) ... any other random thougths ?

Comment: @Selvin "prolly" is your assumption as we cannot see that code.

Comment: And you are assuming that OP is not using this ... :D

Comment: I do not suppose nothing. I reply to what I see in the question.

Comment: *I reply to what I see in the question* ... we cannot see the code

Comment: Let's leave it here. have a nice day.

Comment: Well .we have code now ... And I was right ... have a nice day

Comment: So kudos for you. Nice guessing skills.

Answer (score 1):

You need to query as below:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Products] WHERE name LIKE **N**'%می%'
```

The preceding "N" I added after LIKE word, lets SQL Server know that your query should be considered as nvarchar encoding (not varchar).

Comment: Sounds like you're suggesting sql injection.

Comment: What do you mean by suggesting sql injection??? you can find more in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380652/sql-server-query-what-is-the-meaning-of-n-preceding-a-string

Comment: While that raw sql should work, the question is asking for C# code to run a query with a parameter. So suggesting raw sql as an "Answer", implies that the OP should format the raw query... which might allow for sql injection.

Comment: What I suggested is raw sql. We have varchar and **n**varchar datatypes in sql server. This "n" in nvarchar is related to **n** in "like N'%کورش%'". We you define your data type as nvarchar in EF, EF will add this **N** when you are "like" filtering by this column. You can double check it in Sql Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code like this and it worked

```
public List<Products> SearchByName(string query)
    {
        SqlParameter p1 = new("@query", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)
        {
            Value = $"%{query}%"
        };
        List<SqlParameter> param = new() { p1 };
        return _exteranldata.GetFromCommand<Products>("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Products] WHERE name LIKE @query", param);
    }
```

Note: The name type in the database is nvachar(50) but for reasons I don't know this query doesn't work on nvarchar and you need to change the data type sent to varchar.